# What is a Measured Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, letters, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Measured Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Examples of Measured Words™]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version: (If you copy this text elsewhere, make sure that your font matches the one in the image above.)

```
Measured Words™,Not Measured Words™
AMITY,DISCORD
BEST,WORST
CLAW,TALON
DAM,WALL
DYE,COLOR
MILK,WATER
MOTH,FLY
NEST,DEN
OX,BULL
PAW,HOOF
REST,WALK
SLY,SIMPLE
WOLF,TIGER
ZESTY,MILD
```

> You've had a stroke of good luck! I'm giving you a hint.

Comment: Are all the examples still Measured Words™ in the fixed width section at the bottom?

Comment: @PlayerOne The text at the bottom is exactly the same as the text in the table. The table is for a nice presentation and the simple text is so people can copy / paste if they want to do some analysis.

Comment: The text is the same, but the font is different. The letter I in the table has no horizontal bars on the top or bottom, but it does in the fixed width text, which seems like it might matter if the font is important to the solution :)

Comment: @PlayerOne I can't control the plaintext font for every user. That's why I use the image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I got it, a Measured Word™ is:

> A word in which if we replace every letter with the sum of strait lines and curves, we get the sequence `1234`
>  repeating with some offset. 
>  
>  E.g.
>
> ```
> AMITY becomes 34123 and 
> WOLF becomes 4123
> ```

Comment: And *that* is why font mattered. [Good jorb](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1wBrC.png).